# Secure to install DHCP and gateway services on the same machine?

Tags: security, dhcp

What considerations would you have when deciding on installing the DCHP services onto a machine currently serving in the gateway role.

What issues/concerns/considerations would you have in this scenario. Cost isn't the concern, but rather security, maintainability. Anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a DHCP service on your gateway is not insecure, in itself. But it's also not the most secure option, either. Any network service can potentially lead to a compromise, if the service has a security vulnerability, or isn't properly configured.

The added risk would be pretty small if you take some basic security precautions:

- The DHCP service should only listening on the local, internal network.
- Research whether your DHCP server software has any known remote vulnerabilities. If you find any, consider switching to an alternative DHCP implementation.
- Patch/upgrade your DHCP server software promptly when security fixes are released.
- Periodically check the DHCP server logs for suspicious activity.

These are just the standard security practices that apply to any service, on any host. It's still possible that an internal attacker could exploit a zero-day vulnerability in your DHCP service, but that's the best guarantee you can get with any service.

But there's no universal answer to this question. Each person needs to weigh the risks versus the costs for himself and his organization.

Comment: +1 for thoughtful answer, especially patching and monitoring.  As you say, good practice for any server/host.

Comment: Completely agree. This really applies to all services running on a host exposed to the Internet. Be mindful of what you expose yourself to. Proper configuration goes a *long* way though.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to have the DHCP server assigned to the correct interface, and that UDP ports 67 and 68 aren't open to the outside (unless you have some sort of relay configuration set up).  Should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what angle you look at it - You're making yourself **more** insecure, not nessasarily insecure enough to justify not implementing DHCP through your gateway, but you're leading yourself into some issues. Heres some questions you can answer for yourself to see if you justify the worth

- Do you have multiple users that can
  administer the gateway/DHCP server?
- If so, what sort of password
  requirements are in place?
- Is your server strictly RFC 2131 compliant or does it support 3118 across multiple subnets? (Keep in mind that you can VLAN/Area hop very easily with a hijacked DHCP server that supports authentication)
- Is the gateway also used as an IS-IS L2 or L1+2 area?

If you're concerned with security, its worth keeping in mind the serious implications of a compromise of either your DHCP server by external attackers, but also of the implications of internal attacks compromising your data integrity.

I think Ryan gave some of the most sound advice in any case - Be vigilant, Keep yourself updated on attacker methodologies, and review logs when time permits.